# Status bar Notification not showing up

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have simple notification setup that should show notification on the status bar when the time arrives(Basically remainder). I set the time like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2016, 0, 30, 10, 56, 00);
        alarmReceiver.setCredentials(NAME,PODCAST);
        setAlarm(cal);
```

The `setAlarm` method is given here:

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar target){

    Toast.makeText(c, "Reminder set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), req1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, target.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

This calls `AlarmReciever` class which is:

```
  public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static int notifyId=1;
String name="";
String disc="";
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
PendingIntent pIntent;
NotificationManager manager;
Intent resultIntent;
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder;
public void setCredentials(String n,String d){
    name=n;
    disc=d;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm has been set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Midhun","onReceiver receiver...");
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    //set title for NOTIFICATION
    notification.setContentTitle(name);
    //message in notification
    notification.setContentText(disc);
    //Alert shown when notification recieved
    notification.setTicker("INVENTO 16");
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify);
    stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(10,notification.build());
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**The problem**  is that the Notification is not showing up.

I have tried following:

1.I printed a statement from `AlarmReceiver` class just to see if that method is called.And the message is displayed in the console at the correct time(The time that i set in the line:  `cal.set(2016, 0, 30, 08, 56, 00);`) ie. @ 8:56 on 30 jan 2015.

2.Also the Toast that is displayed when `setAlarm` is called.

So basically the problem is My AlarmReciever class.But i'm unable to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it started working for me when i removed the statement `stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);`